# Get a count of items with a certain condition within a StackPanel's Children

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I have an custom `UserControl` I created

```
public class MyObject : UserControl
{
    public MyObject()
    {

    }
    public bool IsFinished { get; set; }
}
```

I added lets say 10(will be dynamic) `MyObject`'s to a StackPanel and every other item i set `IsFinished` to true.

```
private void DoSomething()
{
    StackPanel panel = new StackPanel();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        int rem = 0;
        Math.DivRem(i, 2, out rem);
        MyObject newObj = new MyObject();
        if (rem == 0)
        {
            newObj.IsFinished = true;
        }
        panel.Children.Add(newObj);
    }
}
```

Now I can add the following and get the answer I am looking for (5)

```
int FinishedItems = 0;
foreach (object o in panel.Children)
{
    if (o.GetType() == typeof(MyObject))
    {
        if (((MyObject)o).IsFinished)
        {
            FinishedItems++;
        }
    }
}
```

2 Questions:

A. Is there a more eloquent way? maybe with `Linq` I'm still learning how to use that. From what I understand, that is what LINQ technically does.

B. Am I wrong about LINQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to count the finished items:

```
int FinishedItems = panel.Children.OfType<MyObject>()
                         .Count(mo => mo.IsFinished);
```

Comment: Thats the ticket. I've been banging my head for too long on this and actually just stumbled on OfType and was playing with this exact code. Thank you. About the second question just for knowledge purpose. Is LINQ basically just doing a loop to get the answer anyways?

Answer (score 2):

You may try:

```
int FinishedItems = panel.Children.OfType<MyObject>().Where(mo=>mo.IsFinished).Count();
```